# Mark as Date Table seems to be pointless

Tags: powerbi

The [Feb 2018](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-february-2018-feature-summary/#customDateTable) update to Power BI included the ability to mark a table as a 'Date Table'.

One would assume that this would give you the ability to import your date table once and use values from that table to build hierarchies for dates on other tables in the report (e.g. our financial year).

I can't currently see what the point of this whole feature is, after I mark my date table as a date table, it's still using the built-in date hierarchies for dates on any other table I import and i can't use values from my date table without a relationship between the date columns.

What's the point of this feature if i still have to import the date table once for each date field I want to analyse and set it as a relationship? Am I completely missing something, is it a bug?

Both the update video and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-date-tables) explain how to mark a table as a date table, but don't explain what use it is.

The feature is only 6 days old, so possible that it's not functioning as intended, but it would be nice to understand how it was intended to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you already have a custom date table and you're not seeing the value of marking it as such. In other words, you're **not** asking why you'd use a custom date table in general (which is a slightly different question to the one I'm answering).

This isn't intended to be a comprehensive answer, but I think the main value of marking a custom date table as a date table is if you had run into something that didn't work previously because you couldn't mark it as such.

For example, in this thread from 2016, Greggyb mentions that a custom date table in Power BI import mode must be joined using a date datatype field, rather than an integer field, to use the built-in time functions in DAX: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-mark-Date-table/td-p/3202/page/2.

As another example, the Quick Measures documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quick-measures#limitations-and-considerations) mentions that to use a custom date table as the basis of a Quick Measure, the table must be marked as a date table:

> **If your data model has a custom date table**, you can use the primary
>   date column in that table for time intelligence quick measures. You
>   must ensure that when the model was built, **that primary date column in
>   that table was marked as a Date table**, as described in this article.

(*emphasis mine*)

---

If you haven't run into anything that required you to mark your custom date table as a date table, then I wouldn't expect that marking it now would make any difference to you. If you had previously run into something that required you to mark as a date table, I expect you'd have already worked around it now, so this change would still be of limited value. Overall, I'd say this feature is more so that using a custom date table with built-in DAX time functions is smoother in future.

Comment: I don't want believe this is the only functionality it adds, but it seems you are correct. I could get around the DAX formula problem by editing the quick measure, but having my users import the date table once for each date in a model that can have 20+ date columns is a nightmare!  I thought they had actually replaced all of the internal date table functions based on the vague description, ah well :/

Comment: The description/documentation on this feature is very confusing. They talk about it as if it allows custom date tables for the first time, which isn't true. And as your question says, they talk about how to mark it without ever mentioning why you'd want to.

Comment: Generally, I bring in one date table, and relate the main date in each fact table to that one date table. The only time I bring in secondary date tables is if I want to plot a fact against 2 different dates at the same time (e.g. if I have open dates vs. close dates - then I might relate the open date to my main date table and have a secondary date table for the close date).